# Validate parameters in async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm writing a class which have synchronous and asynchronous versions of the same method 
`void MyMethod(object argument)` and `Task MyMethodAsync(object argument)`. In sync version I validate argument with the simple check

```
if (argument == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("argument");
```

How should the same check look like in async method?

1) Same as for sync method

2) (Updated after first answer)

```
if (argument == null)
    return new Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new ArgumentNullException("argument"); });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That depends a bit on when you want the error to be raised - i.e. eagerly, or as part of the awaitable. As with iterator blocks, if you want eager error checks, you need two methods, for example:

```
public Task<int> SomeMethod(..args..) {
    if(..args fail..) throw new InvalidOperationException(...);
    return SomeMethodImpl(...args...);
}
private async Task<int> SomeMethodImpl(...args...)
{
    ... await etc ...
}
```

This will then perform any argument checking *as part of the initial call*, not the awaitable. If you want the exception to be part of the awaitable, you can just throw it:

```
public async Task<int> SomeMethod(..args..) {
    if(..args fail..) throw new InvalidOperationException(...);
    ... await etc ...
}
```

However, in your example, the fact that you are `return`ing a `Task` suggests that this is not actually an `async` method, but is an *async* (but not `async`) method. You can't just do:

```
return new Task(() => { throw new ArgumentNullException("argument"); });
```

because that `Task` will never have been started - and never will be. I *suspect* you would need to do something like:

```
try {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException(...); // need to throw to get stacktrace
} catch(Exception ex) {
    var source = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    source.SetException(ex);
    return source.Task;
}
```

which is... a bit of a mouthful and could probably be encapsulated a bit better. This will return a `Task` that indicates it is in the `Faulted` state.

Comment: Target framework is 4.0 so I'm not using async and await keywords

Comment: Second option should be written as Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw ... }); Updated it in question

Comment: @Demarsch just add [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) and `async` / `await` will work fine

Comment: @Demarsch re the `StartNew` - there is no point in queuing a worker thread to do this; you could take that code with `TaskCompletionSource` and encapsulate it - that is far more efficient.

Comment: Alas I don't see non generic version of TaskCompletionSource that could return Task with no return value

Comment: @Demarsch it doesn't matter - any `Task<T>` is also a `Task` - `Task<bool>` will work fine

Comment: @Demarsch starting a new Task does not create a worker thread.

Answer (score 15):

Starting from C# 7.0, you can use use [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) to reduce noise in code but still be compliant with argument check practice from [sonar rule S4457](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-4457).
For example, this code will throw an ArgumentNullException in both cases: if you call it with await or without.

```
private Task WaitSeconds(int? durationInSeconds)
{
    if(durationInSeconds == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(durationInSeconds));
    async Task WaitSecondsInternal()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(durationInSeconds.Value));
    }
    return WaitSecondsInternal();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply throw it like you did in the sync method, the TPL has various mechanisms in place to re-throw exception, for example when you read the .`Result` property or the access .`Exception` property.

Answer (score 2):

As per [sonar rule S4457](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-4457)

> Because of the way async/await methods are rewritten by the compiler, any exceptions thrown during the parameters check will happen only when the task is observed. That could happen far away from the source of the buggy code or never happen for fire-and-forget tasks.
>
> Therefore it is recommended to split the method into two: an outer method handling the parameter checks (without being async/await) and an inner method to handle the iterator block with the async/await pattern.
>
> This rule raises an issue when an async method throws any exception derived from ArgumentException and contains await keyword.

### Noncompliant Code Example

```
public static async Task SkipLinesAsync(this TextReader reader, int linesToSkip) // Noncompliant
{
    if (reader == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(reader)); }
    if (linesToSkip < 0) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(linesToSkip)); }

    for (var i = 0; i < linesToSkip; ++i)
    {
        var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (line == null) { break; }
    }
}
```

---

### Compliant Solution

```
public static Task SkipLinesAsync(this TextReader reader, int linesToSkip)
{
    if (reader == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(reader)); }
    if (linesToSkip < 0) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(linesToSkip)); }

    return reader.SkipLinesInternalAsync(linesToSkip);
}

private static async Task SkipLinesInternalAsync(this TextReader reader, int linesToSkip)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < linesToSkip; ++i)
    {
        var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (line == null) { break; }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what SonarQube says. (Did you write that?) I still don't understand why the compliant solution is better. The compiler only generates a seperate method for the awaited part, so my stack trace would show errors that correspond perfectly with my source code. (I just tested this)

Comment: Note that when an exception in the SkipLinesInternalAsync occurs the SkipLinesAsync is no longer part of the stacktrace.

Comment: This rule gives me problems and breaks existing code: I and previous developers expected async methods to always behave async. This means: fire-and-forget and never throw exception, always return AggregateException when running into error with .Wait() or .Result. Apart from the ugly code, this rule breaks the async pattern, and any code that relies on it. What about less trivial parameter checks than for null, where you don't know if the check runs into deeper layers and other async code? .Wait()/.Result seem inevitable when trying to wait for completion of multiple and get all exceptions.