# Parameter validation in "async"/"await" methods should be wrapped

Tags: c#, sonarqube

Why is SonarQube complaining in this code? I read explanation, but din't really understand why and what I need to do, to make it go away.

[Link to SonarQube Rule](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-4457)

```
public async Task Add(SomeModel obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));
    }
    var obj2 = new OtherObject();
    obj2.UpdateWith(obj);
    await _localDatabaseService.AddAsync(obj2);
}
```

Changing code to look like this does not resolve issue.

```
public Task Add(SomeModel obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));
    }
    return AddInternal(obj);
}
private async Task AddInternal(SomeModel obj)
{
    var obj2 = new OtherObject();
    obj2.UpdateWith(obj);
    await _localDatabaseService.AddAsync(i);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate parameters in async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656379/validate-parameters-in-async-method)

Comment: Note that you can make that `AddInternal` a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) inside `Add` (using C# 7+) - same effect but you cannot call AddInternal without going through Add

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just tried your examples and the issue isn't raised on your second code (replacing `AddAsync(i)` with `AddAsync(obj2)` to match first code logic.

Regarding the explanation of the rule I think the website is pretty clear but let me provide a code sample to try and illustrate the wrong behavior.

```
static async void Main(string[] args)
{
    var x = new Program().Add(null); // Exception is not raised here...

    // do some other things

    await x; // ... but here when awaited
}
```

As you can see the issue isn't raised when you expect it.

Obviously, if you are sure that you NEVER end up in this kind of situation and that no-one would use your method in this way you can turn-off the rule.