# Why is wrapping parameter validation in a non-async method desirable?

Tags: c#, async-await, sonarqube

I've had [this](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-4457) warning pop up in SonarQube but I don't understand why wrapping the validation is desirable.

I've read the following questions but neither appears to explain clearly WHY it is better?

[Parameter validation in "async"/"await" methods should be wrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50819452/1093406)

[Validate parameters in async method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18656379/1093406)

In the example

```
public async Task DoSomethingAsync(string param){
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(param)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Param is blank");
    }

    await DoSomethingElseAsync(param);
}
```

Why would this be executed any differently to

```
public Task DoSomethingAsync(string param){
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(param)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Param is blank");
    }

    return doSomethingElseAsync(param);
}
```

Given that both implementations would need to be awaited by the caller, would there actually be any guarantee that the validation in the 2nd implementation would be executed immediately rather than be delayed like any other async method?

Comment: It comes down to how exceptions are thrown: in the first, they aren't thrown to the caller, but they're returned as the returned Task's Exception property. In the second, they're thrown directly. Consider `var t = DoSomethingAsync(...); await t;`: for the first snippet, the `await` throws an exception. For the second, the call to `DoSomethingAsync` itself throws

Comment: Which is better... is personal preference. [Bill Wagner](http://www.thebillwagner.com/blog/Item/2013-03-05-AsyncExceptionsandLibraryDesign), for example, prefers your second approach. If memory serves (and I can't find a reference at the moment), Stephen Toub prefers the first.

Comment: You can think about this problem in a different way: Keep your public API as thin as possible. Your public API performs a **preliminary check** then everything else is an implementation detail from the API consumer point of view.

Comment: "would there actually be any guarantee that the validation in the 2nd implementation would be executed immediately rather than be delayed like any other async method?" - yes, because the method literally doesn't use `async` and so doesn't even have an async state machine built from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An asynchronous method is converted by the compiler to a state machine.

When the method is invoked, the state machine is instantiated. And only then, the code before the first `await` is invoked.

If you have this method:

```cs
private static async Task<int> GetValueAsync(object o)
{
    if (o is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(o));
    await Task.Delay(1);
    return 0;
}
```

The generated code will be:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
[CompilerGenerated]
private struct <GetValueAsync>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    public int <>1__state;

    public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int> <>t__builder;

    public object o;

    private TaskAwaiter <>u__1;

    private void MoveNext()
    {
        int num = <>1__state;
        int result;
        try
        {
            TaskAwaiter awaiter;
            if (num != 0)
            {
                if (o == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("o");
                }
                awaiter = Task.Delay(1).GetAwaiter();
                if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
                {
                    num = (<>1__state = 0);
                    <>u__1 = awaiter;
                    <>t__builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(ref awaiter, ref this);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                awaiter = <>u__1;
                <>u__1 = default(TaskAwaiter);
                num = (<>1__state = -1);
            }
            awaiter.GetResult();
            result = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            <>1__state = -2;
            <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
            return;
        }
        <>1__state = -2;
        <>t__builder.SetResult(result);
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in MoveNext
        this.MoveNext();
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    private void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        <>t__builder.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in SetStateMachine
        this.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
    }
}

[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<GetValueAsync>d__0))]
private static Task<int> GetValueAsync(object o)
{
    <GetValueAsync>d__0 stateMachine = default(<GetValueAsync>d__0);
    stateMachine.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int>.Create();
    stateMachine.o = o;
    stateMachine.<>1__state = -1;
    stateMachine.<>t__builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
    return stateMachine.<>t__builder.Task;
}
```

If you validate the parameters in a non-async method:

```cs
private static Task<int> GetValueAsync(object o)
{
    if (o is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(o));
    return GetValueAsyncImpl(o);

    static async Task<int> GetValueAsyncImpl(object o)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The generated code will be:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
[CompilerGenerated]
private struct <<GetValueAsync>g__GetValueAsyncImpl|0_0>d : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    public int <>1__state;

    public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int> <>t__builder;

    private TaskAwaiter <>u__1;

    private void MoveNext()
    {
        int num = <>1__state;
        int result;
        try
        {
            TaskAwaiter awaiter;
            if (num != 0)
            {
                awaiter = Task.Delay(1).GetAwaiter();
                if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
                {
                    num = (<>1__state = 0);
                    <>u__1 = awaiter;
                    <>t__builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(ref awaiter, ref this);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                awaiter = <>u__1;
                <>u__1 = default(TaskAwaiter);
                num = (<>1__state = -1);
            }
            awaiter.GetResult();
            result = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            <>1__state = -2;
            <>t__builder.SetException(exception);
            return;
        }
        <>1__state = -2;
        <>t__builder.SetResult(result);
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in MoveNext
        this.MoveNext();
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    private void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        <>t__builder.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in SetStateMachine
        this.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
    }
}

private static Task<int> GetValueAsync(object o)
{
    if (o == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("o");
    }
    return <GetValueAsync>g__GetValueAsyncImpl|0_0(o);
}

[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<<GetValueAsync>g__GetValueAsyncImpl|0_0>d))]
[CompilerGenerated]
internal static Task<int> <GetValueAsync>g__GetValueAsyncImpl|0_0(object o)
{
    <<GetValueAsync>g__GetValueAsyncImpl|0_0>d stateMachine = default(<<GetValueAsync>g__GetValueAsyncImpl|0_0>d);
    stateMachine.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int>.Create();
    stateMachine.<>1__state = -1;
    stateMachine.<>t__builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
    return stateMachine.<>t__builder.Task;
}
```

Which does not instantiate the state machine if there are invalide parameter values.

The same happens for iterator methods.

Comment: This doesn't touch on the actual critical difference, which is how the exception is propagated up: by being thrown, vs being set as the Task's Exception property

Comment: Thanks. That does explain the difference well. I guess this also means that the 2nd example would be faster too because its making one state machine instead of 2? Although possibly not measurably unless in a tight loop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the caller will invoke and `await` the asynchronous method sequentially, there is no difference.

```
await DoSomethingAsync("Chess");
await DoSomethingAsync("Stratego");
await DoSomethingAsync(null);
```

But how can you be sure about that? The caller might just as well separate the phase of creating the tasks, and the phase of awaiting them.

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(DoSomethingAsync("Chess"));
tasks.Add(DoSomethingAsync("Stratego"));
tasks.Add(DoSomethingAsync(null));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

In this case the two different `DoSomethingAsync` implementations will result to different behaviors in the caller's code.

One more difference is with the [XML documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/) of the method, assuming that you want to be consistent with [Microsoft's guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags). The first implementation requires no [`<exception>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags#exception) element, because no exception can be thrown synchronously:

```
/// <summary>Does something asynchronously.</summary>
/// <param name="param">The parameter.</param>
/// <returns>A <see cref="Task"/> that will complete when something is done.</returns>
public async Task DoSomethingAsync(string param)
{
    // ...
}
```

The second implementation does require an `<exception>` element, because an `ArgumentException` can be thrown synchronously:

```
/// <summary>Does something asynchronously.</summary>
/// <param name="param">The parameter.</param>
/// <returns>A <see cref="Task"/> that will complete when something is done.</returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException"><paramref name="param"/> is blank.</exception>
public Task DoSomethingAsync(string param)
{
    // ...
}
```